# Deploying new version of google script webapp requires a new link

Tags: deployment, web-deployment

I am trying to deploy a google script webapp.  I have to use a new link for every new version even though i tried the following process.

1. Deploy the version -- call it version A link.
2. Make it the new version by clicking on the pencil icon at the top right to edit this deployment. Click on the "Version" dropbox and "New version". Then "Deploy". It gives me the same link - version A link.
3. I make a change and deploy it - I get a new link for this version - call it version B link.
4. I make version b the new version by Make it the new version by clicking on the pencil icon at the top right to edit this deployment. Click on the "Version" dropbox and "New version". Then "Deploy". It gives me the same link - version B link.
5. I click on the version A link and it is still giving me the original version A and does not include the changes i made.
6. I tried to use the link that is obtained when I click on test deployment and it seems to give the latest version.  However, it requires someone else to be signed in on google for it to work.  I need it to work without signing in b/c some people that will use this do not have google accounts.
7. What am i missing?